# How do I select these member variables in this data structure

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got tasked with trying to retrieve the cities from these countries. However, I am uncertain of how I would obtain them? What is the easiest way to get the city-names like:

For USA it would be: NYC, SFO.

I've tried like this: `cityData[0].children[0]` but that just gives me `Object object`.

How can I target the cities for each country?

```
var cityData = [
    {country: "USA", children:[
        {"NYC": ["60%", "70%", "80%"]}, 
        {"SFO": ["40%", "30%", "20%"]}
    ]},
    {country: "Mexico", children:[
        {"Mexico City": ["80%", "80%", "80%"]}, 
        {"Cancun": ["20%", "20%", "20%"]}
    ]},
    {country: "Canada", children:[
        {"Toronto": ["50%", "60%", "60%"]}, 
        {"Vancouver": ["50%", "40%", "40%"]}
    ]
}];
```

Is there another way of accessing the city name than by doing: `cityData[0].children['NYC']` and `cityData[0].children['SFO']`?

I need them both but with one selector (if that makes sense).

Feel free to change the data structure to a more detailed one if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to access the key(s) of the object(s) that you are looking at, it will return an array of the keys. You can use a map to obtain the keys on each object to return an array of cities. This will return an array of cities

```
cityData[0].children.map(itm => Object.keys(itm)[0])
```

```js
var cityData = [
    {country: "USA", children:[
        {"NYC": ["60%", "70%", "80%"]}, 
        {"SFO": ["40%", "30%", "20%"]}
    ]},
    {country: "Mexico", children:[
        {"Mexico City": ["80%", "80%", "80%"]}, 
        {"Cancun": ["20%", "20%", "20%"]}
    ]},
    {country: "Canada", children:[
        {"Toronto": ["50%", "60%", "60%"]}, 
        {"Vancouver": ["50%", "40%", "40%"]}
    ]
}];


console.log(cityData[0].children.map(itm => Object.keys(itm)[0]))
```

Comment: Also what does the selector need to look like?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   for(let key in cityData[0].children[0]) {
       console.log(key);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact syntax you suggest can be had if you preprocess the children arrays first, to be objects...

```js
var cityData = [
    {country: "USA", children:[
        {"NYC": ["60%", "70%", "80%"]}, 
        {"SFO": ["40%", "30%", "20%"]}
    ]},
    {country: "Mexico", children:[
        {"Mexico City": ["80%", "80%", "80%"]}, 
        {"Cancun": ["20%", "20%", "20%"]}
    ]},
    {country: "Canada", children:[
        {"Toronto": ["50%", "60%", "60%"]}, 
        {"Vancouver": ["50%", "40%", "40%"]}
    ]
}];

cityData.forEach(country => {
    let childrenObj = {}
    country.children.forEach(city => {
        let key = Object.keys(city)[0]
        childrenObj[key] = key
    })
    country.children = childrenObj
})

console.log(cityData[0].children['NYC'])
```

Comment: @Joel - Easy change.  Edited.  Strange though, because you sort of already have the city 'NYC' if you're using it as the index.